# Changing the grid limits when using imagesc

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

so I have a 3x8x8 logical comprising of 0's and 1's (1 indicating significant results, 0 implicating non significant results). It looks like this when I take the first one (iteration_signf_EMG_EMG(:,:,1)):

1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0

1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1

1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0

I wanted to plot this using imagesc, so all 1's will be red and all 0's will be blue, yet the figure is strangely shifted and I can't seem to fix it...

Here is the code I use:

```
imagesc(iteration_signf_EMG_EMG(:,:,1));
set(gca, 'xtick', xbounds(1):1:xbounds(2));
set(gca, 'ytick', ybounds(1):1:ybounds(2));
colorbar
grid on
```

Here is the output figure:
[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTbpp.png)
Here is what I want it to look like:
[what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IUoP.png)

I hope you guys can help me!

Cheers

Comment: The only difference I could spot between the two figures you posted is the x- and y-axis tick labels.  Is that what you want to change?

Comment: Yes, and also the grid should be 3x8 not 6x8 as in the first graphic

Answer (score 0):

The pictures are graphically identical and you should only change your axis to the intervals you want, the code below will change the axis as you want. 
Add this to your script and see the changes.

`axis([1 8 1 3 ]);`

Comment: Hi thanks, yet this doesn't seem to solve my problem. I want there to be three rows and eight columns which are are labeled as such and so therefore the grid should look like the one I outlined with paint in the second graphic I uploaded for my original post - any idea how I can achieve this?